# NameError: name 'AF_INET' is not defined (ONLY ON MAC)

Tags: python, sockets

So I have python installed in three places: A Windows machine, a Pi (Running Kali), and my Mac. My Mac is the only one where I get this error when either importing the socket library or a library dependent upon the socket library (i.e. ipwhois). I ran it in sudo, I tried both python 2 and 3 and still no success. Here is what I get:

```
Python 2.7.14 (default, Oct  1 2017, 15:09:23) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 9.0.0 (clang-900.0.37)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

>>>import socket
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "socket.py", line 15, in <module>
    serverSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
NameError: name 'AF_INET' is not defined
>>> import ipwhois
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/user/homebrew/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ipwhois/__init__.py", line 26, in <module>
    from .net import Net
  File "/Users/user/homebrew/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ipwhois/net.py", line 26, in <module>
    import socket
  File "socket.py", line 15, in <module>
    serverSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
NameError: name 'AF_INET' is not defined
```

Again, no issues with either of these libraries on my Windows or Linux box. I'm not really sure where to go from here. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: `socket` is a module from the standard library, so this is weird. If you get that error from a clean directory (no python file there), it is time to re-install Python.

Comment: So it seems that if I move it the directory above the current one, it works. Weird...

Comment: Or any directory above that directory for that matter. So far. No permission issues I'm seeing in that directory so far.

Answer (score 5):

`AF_INET` is define inside the `socket`, so try the below way:

```
from socket import AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM
```

If you want to know what it include inside the `socket` try the follow way:

```
import socket

print dir(socket)
```

Comment: Same result :(.

Comment: check your file name ，don’t use std library name as your self module name,from you error information, it’s show line 15, it’s clearly mean you have define a self module name the same as system library,maybe you can try to use mysocket.py

Answer (score 3):

From your comment, the error occurs in one specific directory. The `socket` module tries to import some other modules, notably `_socket`. If you have a file with this name in current directory, bad things are guaranteed to occur. The general rule is that you should never have a user module starting with a `_` or re-using the name of a module from the standard library.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and this worked for me.

Get all the parameters form the socket module.

```
from socket import *
```